# ApolloServer 2.0: Strange entries in playground settings JSON

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

I'm running Apollo Server 2.0 with Express to prototype a GraphQL API. Here's what my ApolloServer init looks like (part of my server script):

```
// GraphQL: Schema
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    endpoint: `/blog/`,
    settings: './playground.json'
  }
});
```

Following what's suggested on the [Prisma Github page](https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-playground#settings), I have the settings value abstracted out into a separate JSON file that looks like this:

```
// playground.json
{
  "general.betaUpdates": false,
  "editor.cursorShape": "line",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro', 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Monaco', monospace",
  "editor.theme": "dark",
  "editor.reuseHeaders": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "request.credentials": "omit",
  "tracing.hideTracingResponse": true
}
```

This setup works just fine. Except when I run the server and view the settings loaded into the playground in the browser, I notice some strange, albeit harmless, entries in the JSON:

```
{
  "0": ".",
  "1": "/",
  "2": "p",
  "3": "l",
  "4": "a",
  "5": "y",
  "6": "g",
  "7": "r",
  "8": "o",
  "9": "u",
  "10": "n",
  "11": "d",
  "12": ".",
  "13": "j",
  "14": "s",
  "15": "o",
  "16": "n",
  "general.betaUpdates": false,
  "editor.cursorShape": "line",
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Source Code Pro', 'Consolas', 'Inconsolata', 'Droid Sans Mono', 'Monaco', monospace",
  "editor.theme": "dark",
  "editor.reuseHeaders": true,
  "prettier.printWidth": 80,
  "request.credentials": "omit",
  "tracing.hideTracingResponse": true
}
```

Any idea what could possibly be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playground settings should be object, but you provide string. You can fix that with `require`.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    endpoint: `/blog/`,
    settings: require('./playground.json')
  }
});
```

Server provides only default settings. Browser has local settings and makes composing.